# Why are the keys named Ctrl & Alt?

Tags: keyboard, hotkeys, ctrl, alt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the origins of the control and alt keys?](https://superuser.com/questions/174945/what-are-the-origins-of-the-control-and-alt-keys)

I use these keys often as modifiers for shortcuts including the infamous copy and paste and some tab-switching but I don't understand why they're named `Ctrl` and `Alt`.

Why are they named the way they are?